# How to force new user to reset password from CRM on first login?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is there any options to force a new user created in MS Dynamics CRM 2016 to change their password? I can see in AD there is an option you can tick 'User must change password at next logon'.

Comment: I would definately try the Active Directory approach that you asked about in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. This is more of an AD user account setting.

The Dynamics CRM System user records are getting synced from AD, then used for Single sign on using ADFS challenge. If the user is accessing Outlook web or CRM or SharePoint for the first time after onboarded, that time anyway he/she has to change the password. Sometimes even in Windows login it may be prompted to do so.

So this has nothing to do with CRM, there is no option to configure and this login screen does not belong to CRM at all.